# Volleyball - Is this reaching over the net?

Tags: rules, officiating, volleyball

This is a follow-up question to the "In volleyball when is it considered reading over the net" question posted a few years ago.

Subject of this question, is the accompanying play [starting at time index 54:07](https://youtu.be/ncOrlCaoHlg?t=3247).

(Ok, so the Team Blue player failed the attack)

Am I wrong here? or did the Team Red & White blockers just barely jump the gun and reach over the net just before the third contact?
The bump(set) was not necessarily in the direction of the opponents court, but seemed parallel to the net.

(The Referees never made any calls to this effect, nor did they throughout the rest of the match despite some other possibly questionable blocking plays.
I assume by the referees not calling anything that everything was legal)

If it was not legal play, can someone explain to me from the rules where the referees or players may have made the mistake?

(I'm just curious because I've run into similar situations in my rec. league.)

Would someone with more experience/better perspective be able to shed some light on this?

Comment: Which ruleset are you interested in when looking for an answer, because the match in question clearly wasn't being played under FIVB rules?

Answer (score 3):

If we would consider the play under standard (FIVB) rules, there is no issue here at all; the blocking players did not even touch the ball. The “reaching over the net” rule refers only to *playing the ball* beyond the net, not just literally “reaching over the net”, without touching the ball nor interfering with opponent play.

You can reach beyond (or under) the net any time you want, unless you touch the ball there or interfere with the play in another way (e.g. by preventing the opponent from playing the ball).